# How to remove \n inside the quotes

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to remove `\n` from a string in single quote which itself is inside the double quotes.

For eg:

```
"\n 'Pitch avec Laura Cobo \n 
 importantes très régulièrement mais à présent \n\n\n' \n"
```

After removing `\n` the line should be like this.

```
"\n 'Pitch avec Laura Cobo importantes très régulièrement mais à présent' \n"
```

The commands I tried

```
=> (.*?(?:"[^"]*"*.*?)*)\r?\n
=> ([^"]*)\n([^"]*)
=> (["])(\\?)[\s\S]*?\1 | [e]*
```

Comment: You probably need to use two backslashes to escape the backslash, as it is part of the sequence you are trying to match. For example: ".*'(.*\\n)+'.*"

Comment: What language / environment it is?

Comment: I am using ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not elegant, but I am still a beginner at Ruby.

```
 input_string = "\n 'Pitch avec Laura Cobo \n  
 importantes très régulièrement mais à présent \n\n\n' \n"  

symbol = "'"  

temp_string = input_string[/#{symbol}(.*?)#{symbol}/m, 1]  

first_apo = input_string.index("'")  
last_apo = input_string.rindex("'")  

size = input_string.size  

modified_string = temp_string.gsub(/(\n)/, "")  

result = input_string[0..first_apo] + modified_string + input_string[last_apo..size]  

puts result
```

Please let me know if this works for you, it worked on my computer using Ruby 2.2.5p319